# how to use Exceptions in C++ program?

Tags: c++, exception

hey , i am trying to inherit the exception class and make a new class called NonExistingException:
i wrote the following code in my h file:

```
class NonExistingException : public exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()  {return "Exception: could not find 
     Item";}
};
```

in my code before i am sending something to a function i am writing

```
try{
    func(); // func is a function inside another class
}
catch(NonExistingException& e)
{
    cout<<e.what()<<endl;
}
catch (exception& e)
{
     cout<<e.what()<<endl;
}
```

inside func i am throwing an exception but nothing catches it.
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you throwing? It should look like this: `throw NonExistingVehicleException();`

Comment: Note: Best to catch by const reference.

Comment: You must throw the exception as "throw NonExistingException()", not "throw new NonExistingException()".

Comment: Can you show us the code where you actually throw the exception?

Comment: yes this is what i am doing "throw NonExistingException()"

Comment: @Nadav Stern: Not that we do not believe you but just to verify why not show the code so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @Martin: Maybe I'm missing something. Can you explain what exactly is supposed to be "better" when catching an exception by const-ref compared to non-const-ref?

Comment: for some reason it works now ... i got  no idea why it caused a problem in the first place thank you all !

Comment: @sellibitze: Do you plan to modify the exception at any point? If the answer is no why not use a const reference and give the compiler the opportunity to take advantage of extra information! But "Scott Myers" has a much more lucid write up in his book "Exceptional C++"

Comment: @Martin: So, "better" just translates to "you cannot accidentally modify the exception object". Frankly, I don't care much about that when the catch clause just contains something like `cout<<x.what();`. BTW: Did you mean Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++ or Scott Meyers' Effective C++ ? :-p

Comment: @ sellibitze: Either one will do. You obviously need to read them :-p (Joke) But no it means I am too tiered to think about it and you should read a book about the subject. But Frankly the whole point of C++ is Type and half that battle is getting const correctness done properly.

Comment: @sellibitze:  const-correctness is a tool that helps programmers build better programs.  Detractors generally either don't get it or are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Martin: I actually have Scott's book. And, of course I'm aware of "const-correctness". I should have phrased my question differently: "How is it better *besides* the const-correctness thing?". In this instance (`cout << x.what()`) I couldn't care less about const-correctness. So, unless there are some other compelling reasons why I should use a ref-to-const in a catch cluase, I'll stick with my current style, thank you very much. Not every one of Scott's Effective C++ rules is compelling. For example, returning const objects by value (instead of non-const) is another I don't care about ;)

Comment: @Martin: I didn't find anything to that effect (catching exceptions via const-ref) in Scott's book. And I don't consider non-const references to be a problem here because the catch clause with a non-const reference basically feels like a polymorphic version of pass-by value since the catch clause is the only one having a reference to the object and nobody else would notice a mutation. So, catching by const-ref doesn't really add any security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this:

```
// Derive from std::runtime_error rather than std::exception
// runtime_error's constructor can take a string as parameter
// the standard's compliant version of std::exception can not
// (though some compiler provide a non standard constructor).
//
class NonExistingVehicleException : public std::runtime_error
{
    public:
       NonExistingVehicleException()
         :std::runtime_error("Exception: could not find Item") {}
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw NonExistingVehicleException();
    }
    // Prefer to catch by const reference.
    catch(NonExistingVehicleException const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "NonExistingVehicleException: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    // Try and catch all exceptions
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "std::exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    // If you miss any then ... will catch anything left over.
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception: " << std::endl;
        // Re-Throw this one.
        // It was not handled so you want to make sure it is handled correctly by
        // the OS. So just allow the exception to keep propagating.
        throw;

        // Note: I would probably re-throw any exceptions from main
        //       That I did not explicitly handle and correct.
    }
}
```